# Vectorize dataframe in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, indexing, vectorization

How would you vectorize this for loop in R? This is just a small example but i would need to do this for 11 columns.

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df1)){
  if(df1[i, 'sku2'] == ''){
    df1[i,'sku2'] <- df1[i - 1, 'sku2']
  }
}
return(df1)
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(sku2 = rep(c(1:2, ""), times = 5),
                  a    = rep(c(3:4, ""), times = 5))
```

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532261/fill-blank-rows-depends-on-previous-next-non-empty-value

Comment: I'm having trouble following that example... the main goal of this is to have the fastest possible way to slim down the runtime on this loop. I'm not even sure if vectorization is possible on this loop maybe subsetting would be a better option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task here, if I understand it, is to replace blanks in each column with the most recent non-blank of that column.

Here's a vectorized tidyverse approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
 mutate_all(na_if,"") %>%
 fill(names(df1), .direction = "down)
```

This takes the `df1` data frame, converts blanks to NAs, then uses tidyr::fill on every column to use the last non-blank value.

I expect this will be much faster [edit: it is 100-1000x faster] than your loop, but if you want "the fastest possible" approach, it may be worth looking into approaches using the `data.frame` or `collapse` packages.

##### Performance

For an example with 100,000 rows and 3 columns, this approach was 100x faster: 0.156 seconds instead of 15.5 seconds.

For 200k rows, the loop took 150x as much time: 31 seconds vs. 0.2 seconds.

For 400k rows, the loop was 600x slower: 123 seconds vs. still 0.2 sec for the vectorized version.

I ran out of patience for testing larger data with the loop, but the vectorized version is still only 0.4 seconds with 5 million rows...

```
set.seed(42)
n = 1E5
df1 <- data.frame(sku2 = sample(c(1:4, ""), n, replace = TRUE),
                  sku3 = sample(c(1:8, ""), n, replace = TRUE),
                  sku4 = sample(c(1:20, ""), n, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you for going in depth on this I really appreciate you taking the time !

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right path with vectorization. This for loop can be replaced entirely by using vectorised operations. My approach was using the indexing operator `[]` .

```
df1[df1[1] == "", 1] <- df1[which(df1[1] == "") - 1, 1]
```

`df1[1] == ""` returns a boolean result. I needed to use `which` to convert it into a row number, in order to do `-1` row.

To make it work across 11 columns and to avoid copy paste, here is a function:

```
rm.blank <- function(x){
  df1[df1[x] == "", x]  <- df1[which(df1[x] == "") - 1, x]
  return(df1[x])
}
```

I just did not figure out yet how to write a second function that applies the first function to all columns.
Sooo... I created another for loop.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df1)) {
  df1[i] <- rm.blank(i)
}
```